# I have been using jquery plugin datatable. The scrollBody width is bigger than 100%

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

my problem is that my table use datatable jquery plugin and the width of my table is bigger than 100%, I set the width in my table´s css to 100%, but the table display it is bigger than the container, please help!.

Comment: Do you have javascript and html you could post?

Comment: right now I don´t have the code, but the thing is that I´m using datable to make my table scrollable ´cause is to big, and datatable put the scroll but the table remains with the same size, the same width, the table exceed his div container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solve the problem, in the css that belong to the table adding this line is what fix the problem.

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue posted about here:
[dataTables JS Plugin responsive width overflows set div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345550/datatables-js-plugin-responsive-width-overflows-set-div-width/)

you can remove the set width with the option:

```
"bAutoWidth":false,
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question totally and you have no code to help us to help you, but I think adding this css code will be useful for you:

```
body {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```